# How to purge false errors in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

From time to time in eclipse with ADT, I am getting errors that stick around even after I remove the offending code; in fact, they stay even if I delete the entire content of the file, as per this screen shot:

[image]

The error is `Syntax error on token "}", delete this token`

Suffice to say, there is no such token.

Obviously this is a bug, but what do I do?  My code won't compile as a result.

Comment: usually for me, if I run Lint checking again then it disappears. clean might also do it.

Comment: sorry I'm new to eclipse... where is lint checking?  Clean... does it, though :) also see my answer below

Comment: right click on the project -> android -> run lint. you can also clean all lint markers like the answer below suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the answers given didn't help or weren't the problem (`Clean` in Ran's comment worked, though...).  The easiest fix was CTRL+1, then "Clear All Lint Markers".

Comment: Just to expand -- if you go to the project menu, look under "Android Tools" for "Clear Lint Markers".

Answer (score 3):

Save the the file: Ctrl + S

In eclipse menu: Project - > Clean

Answer (score 3):

For me, just cutting the whole line and pasting it back gets rid of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the supposedly false compiler errors in the [Problems view window](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm), e.g.,[image: delete the supposedly false compiler errors (screen grab)]

Confirm deletion even though `javac` may recreate them:

[image: Confirm deletion even though javac may recreate them (screen grab)]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try cleaning your project and re-build it. It should go.
2. Try restarting adt by going to DDMS>devices>click on the small downward arrow>select "reset adb"
3. Try restarting eclipse.

Any of the above solutions may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting larger content. But some-where at Ending close of bundle which is "}", by mistake you are not deleting it. **So simply delete that "}"**. Then clean-up your project.